# Can't compile program with clang

Tags: c++, templates, clang

I`am trying to compile code bellow. GCC compile it, but clang not.

Error: no member named 'sa' in 'A' static void sf() {A::sa('j');}

What's problem?

test.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
private:

public:
    void f() {this->a('j');}
    static void sf() {A::sa('j');}
#ifdef U
    void a(char x) {}
    static void sa(char x) {}
#endif
};
```

UPD:

I use compilers, that included in Android NDK r10c

gcc 4.9:

cd C:\Tools\android-ndk-r10c\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin

clang++.exe -c C:\Users\Barkov_V\Desktop\test.cpp

clang 3.5:

cd C:\Tools\android-ndk-r10c\toolchains\llvm-3.5\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin

i686-linux-android-gcc-4.9.exe -c C:\Users\Barkov_V\Desktop\test.cpp

Comment: What exact command are you using for the compilation? You'll get that error if you've not defined "U", of course, so make sure that's in the flags. (You'll get the same error with gcc if `U` isn't defined...)

Comment: You code compiles fine for me with, e.g. `clang -c -DU test.cpp`.

Comment: GCC compile this code even if U is not defined, but clang 3.5 not. 'A' is template class, but there is no template instances, so compiler should not compile this code.

P.S. This code is compiled If I comment definition of static function.

Comment: Okay, that's a subtlety I hadn't spotted. It still might be helpful if you updated your question with your exact command lines (and versions of gcc and clang.)

Comment: "should not compile this code." nope, no diagnostic is required.

Comment: Clang does some pre-processing analysis of template code (I believe it is also an option to enable in gcc) to see whether or not it is likely to run into any errors when you do decide to use it later down the line.